# In master-master/multi-master replication, who is the secondary?

Tags: mongodb, ravendb, database-replication

Silly question, when we talk about secondaries in the context of failover behaviour, with regards to master-master/multi-master, is that basically any node other than the one that we are currently reading from or writing to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In master-master replication both the nodes are primary and secondary. In multi master replication every node is secondary but some or all are primary.

Multi master means there many database servers over which write can perform. In order to sync with other data nodes or database server we have to read all other writes and It behaves as secondary. In master slave replication we have only one master and many slaves. Master ensures that he is only write enabled and no one can writes so no need to read any one. and it behave as primary only.

For example- mysql 5.6 replication has support master-master replication but doesn't support multi master replication. But in mysql 5.7 replication it also support multi master replication. In mongoDB It only support master - slave replication.

Comment: And, as I might add, Master/Slave replication is *strongly* discouraged for MongoDB.

Comment: Out of curiosity Markus, why is Master/Slave discouraged for MongoDB?